# I tried to set up Kubernetes executor for gitlab but I get ERROR

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci

I set up Kubernetes executor, but when I tried to run pipeline I got this error:

```
 ERROR: Job failed: image pull failed: Tag x86_64-a3da309 not found in 
 repository docker.io/gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper
```

I set some public docker image in gitlab-ci.yml

Someone have idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under the valid [tags for that image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper/tags/) you'll find the image you're looking for. `x86_64-a3da309d`

So just add a `d` to the tag and it should work.